# How to fix dashed lines spacing in Matlab eps files

Tags: matlab, plot, eps

[image]

There are some issues while saving `eps` files from Matlab. The dashed lines are not printed as it is on saving `eps` format. However, there are several fixes available for them, for example the top ones [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=EPS%20fix%20dotted).

However with newer versions, in my case R2016b, these fix do not work anymore. I tried 4 different submissions in Matlab site. None of them worked. Can anyone help me understand, where in the eps file I have to make the fix? I can do them manually.

Comment: Have you tried using [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) from Yair Altman?  This is the best known FEX package that I know of that accurately saves figures to many formats, including EPS.

Comment: I have been using `matlabfrag` for this actually.

Comment: Why don't you try `export_fig` and see where it takes you?

Comment: I tried `export_fig` and do not see any improvements.

Comment: The flag `-opengl` helps to fix the problem. Again, I have consistently maintaining latex fonts in the paper using `matlabfrag`. Is it possible to generate eps and relevant tex file with `export_fig`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixes available in file exchange ([here](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=EPS%20fix%20dotted)) fail with the eps files of new Matlab versions (mine is R2016b). This is because the Matlab has changed the variable names while writing to a EPS file. The fixes in file exchange search for variables named differently now and therefore, corrupt the EPS files.

I would recommend users to look for `setdash` in the eps opened in `gedit`. For example, I had

```
[2 2] 0 setdash
```

in the file for dashed line.  First variable inside square brackets is for the dash length and the second variable is for the spacing between dashes. This appeared too crowded, almost looking like a continuous line for linewidth of 3. Therefore, I modified

```
[8 8] 0 setdash
```

and it resulted in well-spaced dashed-lines.

Comment: This didn't work for me (R2018a, Mac OS 10.14.5) on lines that have many data points (e.g., smooth curves); I tried values as high as `[8 100] 0 setdash`, but the lines still appeared solid. Changing the rendering engine to OpenGL worked though (see Sayed Raiq answer below).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with R2017a but i found a solution for it.

In the Figure go to Property Editor and klick more properties.

Then set the renderer Mode to manual 
and the renderer to OpenGL.
Then the exchange to eps for every kind of line is working fine.

I think the issue is that the renderer will automatically set to painters and that's why the lines are all solid.

Comment: This solved the problem for me on R2018a, Mac OS 10.14.5

Answer (score 0):

Looks like results for a publication - oh the joys of formatting figures.

You've probably already tried this but have you tried adjusting the `linewidth` parameter eg:

```
plot(x,y,'o-','linewidth',0.5)
```

Also, I am not sure what OS you're using but I am using R2016b on a mac and the following works perfectly:

```
A = rand(8,2);
plot(A(:,1),'r*--','linewidth',0.5);
hold on;
plot(A(:,2),'bs-','linewidth',0.5);
the_saveas_filename=sprintf('./test.eps');
print('-depsc2', the_saveas_filename);
```

Comment: For some reason, I would like to keep the line thickness consistently at 2. I tried with different lower line thickness, the problem still persisted. The same plot, if kept with linear x-axis rather than the current log-scale, the problem is fixed. Since I needed x-axis as log scale, I used dotted lines and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a support ticket regarding this problem and here's MathWorks' response:

> This is a known bug which is fixed with R2017b. Unfortunately, for older releases there is no workaround or patch available.

Comment: you can answer them saying that that#s bs. I am using 2017b and I have the same issue. Sayed's answer actually fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It appears in Matlab 2018a the problem still persists when using `print` function. However, if you use File->Save as.. menu option in a figure window, the dashed lines look better. Unfortunately that option does not let you change any settings.

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon [Sayed Raiq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10568543/sayed-raiq)'s answer, following command works if you need to save a large number of images or need to save within the code:

```
print('save_name','-depsc', '-opengl');
```

However, the rendering resolution is low by default when you use OpenGL renderer.
You can change the resolution using:

```
print('save_name','-depsc', '-opengl', '-r500');
```

Higher the number after the flag `r`, higher the resolution.